# Managing Printers, preferably not GPO

Tags: windows, printer, group-policy

I work for a company that has approximately 3,000 PC's and approximately 1,500 printers. Currently the method to install a printer is rather manual, and we're looking at automating the process. There are certain restrictions that apply to this question:

- Must work on Windows 7 and Windows 10
- Solution cannot be a print server

Apart from that, I have a few personal *preferences* as to the solution:

- Preferably does not require administrative rights to the PC
- Preferably can be managed remotely, i.e. a change to a printer model can be replicated to all users on the domain
- Preferably little scripting needed, as we plan on getting end users to operate this tool.

The current process we're using is to run the following command (or creating a batch script), but this is definitely not a valid solution:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /m "Kyocera FS-4100DN KX" /f "\\share\xfer\PRTscript\_drivers\KXDriver\32bit\OEMsetup.inf"
```

This is not a valid solution as:

1. We can not replicate changes to the clients (unless we house the 'script' on a share
2. It requires administrative rights to install the printers
3. It is a manual task, and fails to distinguish 32 from 64 bit (or at least, it must cater for both)

Now, I know we can use [Group Policies](https://deployhappiness.com/deploying-printers-with-group-policy-preferences/) option to deploy printers, but that is reliant on two things:

1. The OU of the business (or at least, security group) being correct and;
2. The PC's in question are getting Group Policy (they **should**)

And yes, I know Group Policy matches all my requirements AND preferences, but I just want to look at my options before needing to tidy up my OU (and sub-ou, security groups and existing policies) - in the end GPO would be the wisest solution, but I want a *short-term* tool whilst I work on this.

So perhaps, I thought, we could use a simple Visual Basic Script - but again, this requires a lot of manual editing and the only way I can think to automate this would be to deploy via Group Policy:

```
Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
PrinterPath = "\\Server\Printer"
PrinterDriver = "PrinterDriver"
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection PrinterPath, PrinterDriver
WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\Server\Printer"
```

The next theory I can rule out would be to use [PrintBRM](http://ss64.com/nt/printbrm.html)

Comment: So in essence you're looking for an enterprise solution without using any enterprise tools. With those restrictions you should start coding an application for your end users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByhxkwJBdusDczU2MXhrYldfLUU

```
cscript printer.vbs -u ad\username -w <password> -s <computer name>
cscript printer.vbs -u ad\username -w <password> -s <computer name>
cscript printer.vbs -u ad\username -w <password> -s <computer name>
cscript printer.vbs -u ad\username -w <password> -s <computer name>
```

**The point of this script is to install a printer on a remote computer(s) without visiting the location.**

I usually make a list of 25 and copy, paste them into an administrative command window and let them run.

Referring to #3 above 32/64 bit.  My script assume 64 bit, and if that fails then it falls back to 32 bit install.

Installing a printer is going to need admin rights, better you do it then allow a user to do it.

To prevent errors, I delete any existing printer/port with the same name and recreate it.

The username and password are domain credentials, not local.
Maybe this will give you a starting point.
You may have to modify the code so you can add the printer driver info from the command line.  I have mainly the same printer so I hard coded it.  Also the printer name itself could be made a parameter, I just never did it.

I just tweaked the code.

```
cscript printer.vbs -p "Printer Name" -d "HP Universal Printing PS (v6.0.0)" -i "prnhp001.inf" -h "\\<server>\drivers\Printer\prnhp001" -u ad\username -w <password> -s <computer name>
```